# Excel AND Vlookup Checking two values

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I am attempting to create a formula which looks if a value exists within another sheet and then looks to checks to another column in the data array.

If the value exists and the column contains "N" it should say "Yes" otherwise it should say "No".

This is what I've got at the moment but it just says "There's a problem with this Formula".

```
=IF(AND(IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,1,FALSE)),"False","TRUE")="TRUE","TRUE2","FALSE")="TRUE2",IF(IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,1,FALSE)),"False","TRUE")="TRUE","TRUE2","FALSE")="TRUE2", IF(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,11,FALSE)="N"))),"Yes","No")
```

Is there a simpler way or can anyone spot the silly mistake I've made in the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,1,FALSE)),"False","TRUE")="TRUE","TRUE2","FALSE")="TRUE2",IF(IF(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,1,FALSE)),"False","TRUE")="TRUE","TRUE2","FALSE")="TRUE2",IF(VLOOKUP(G143,B10:M137,11,FALSE)="N","Yes","No")="Yes")),"Yes","No")
```

Don't remember what I changed but after fiddling around with it, it works perfectly now. See above for anyone that cares